# how to disable windows speech recognition commands?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am creating a program with python that allows you to do commands with windows speech recognition, the only problem is that i don't want speech recognition to use their default commands. Is there a way to disable this either with python or just disabling it completely. I am using pyspeech for python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what you need is an in-process recognition engine, and PySpeech uses a shared recognition engine.  So you'll need to modify PySpeech a bit.  Change

```
_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpSharedRecognizer")
```

to

```
_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpInprocRecognizer")
```

and in startlistening(phraselist, callback), you need to attach an audio stream (via _recognizer.[SetInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and a reco engine (via _recognizer.[SetRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms718866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Python to translate the SAPI helpers [SpGetDefaultTokenFromCategoryId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717550%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (to get the default audio stream) and [SpGetDefaultSharedRecognizerToken](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/archive/2010/03/01/specifying-parameters-for-an-inproc-recognizer.aspx) (to get the default reco engine) to Python.

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm new to pyspeech and only know a few lines of codes for pyspeech can you give me an example on how i would use this?

Comment: You would need to modify PySpeech's implementation.  Beyond that, I can tell you what to do (and I have), but not how to do it, as I don't know python at all.

Comment: Is there also a way to slowdown the voice when you do speech.say()?

Comment: You can alter the rate via [ISpVoice::SetRate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms719798(v=vs.85).aspx),although you'll need to modify PySpeech to forward the calls), or you can use the [SAPI TTS XML tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717077(v=VS.85).aspx) to alter the rate inline to the text.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still looking for the answer or not but I found it for you!

On line 66 change the code to:

```
_recognizer = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpInProcRecognizer")
_recognizer.AudioInputStream = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpMMAudioIn")
```

And on line 112 change the code to:

```
_ListenerBase = win32com.client.getevents("SAPI.SpInProcRecoContext")
```

This should prevent the windows commands from running while also not showing the widget which comes up. Good luck!

Comment: thank you for the answer. im still working on the same project that i asked this question for, you really helped me.